# Can't upload file to Sharepoint site using Graph API. The resource could not be found

Tags: python, sharepoint, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I can see the files in the drive, but supposedly doesn't exist when trying to write one.

This is how I look for files:

```
site_url = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites
get_url = f"{site_url}/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/root/children"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal",
    "Accept": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal"
}
response = requests.get(get_url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.text)
```

And get the response:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2023-11-13T18:21:22Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-11-13T18:21:22Z",
            "name": "Reporte",
            "webUrl": "{site}/Shared%20Documents/Reporte",
        },
        {
            "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "{download_url}",
            "name": "Open pip.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

Confirming I can access the drive,
But when I try to write a new file:

```
file_name = "Reporte Z.xlsx"
upload_url = f"{site_url}/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{file_name}:/content"

# Set headers
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Connection": "Keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
}

# Read file content
with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
    file_content = file.read()

# Make POST request
response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file_content)

# Check response status
if response.status_code == 201:
    print("File uploaded successfully")
else:
    print("Error uploading file:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

I get the error

```
Error uploading file: 404 {"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"The resource could not be found.","innerError":{"date":"2023-11-13T18:47:51","request-id":"[string]","client-request-id":"[string]"}}}
```

I've tried removing the ":" in root, but get the Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header. Error

I'm following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to no avail.

I've looked in many threads, but many seem to never have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change from POST to PUT. Even in the tutorial says so.

I'll keep this question up in case anyone else is confused.

From:

```
# Make POST request
response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file_content)
```

To:

```
# Make PUT request
response = requests.put(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file_content)
```

I also changed the headers to:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
}
```

Comment: The Microsoft Learn page clearly indicates to use `PUT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http